# H1 tag still has a padding or margin on the bottom even though none set

Tags: html, css

H1 tag still has a padding or margin on the bottom even though none set.

I have a h1 tag and a bit of text underneath. I set margin and madding to 0 on both and the text still does not sit right underneath the h1 text.

I have created a js fiddle to illustrate my point

http://jsfiddle.net/6hCrC/

Comment: There are several brilliant answers to this; just want to add that you can easily check how much space the element is really taking with `border: 1px solid black` rule. )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no padding. There is just space allocated by the default `line-height` and no characters with descenders (like p, q, and g) in the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/6hCrC/1/

Answer (score 5):

Every `font` has their own vertical space which is called **line-height**. It's the `line-height` of **H1**.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6hCrC/4/

Answer (score 3):

Try using `line-height: 70px;`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is something to do with line-height. Perhaps an alternative would be to set a negative margin to the first paragraph.

Here is a jsfiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/6hCrC/3/

Alternatively you could set the line height to a value other than auto (the default)

Answer (score 1):

Ajust the line-height. http://jsfiddle.net/6hCrC/13/

Answer (score 0):

The better solution here is:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4 {line-height: 1em;}
```